# Electron - NPM Modules in Renderer

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, require, electron

I'm having difficulty accessing lodash in an electron renderer.  I'm new to Electron and understand that both the main process and the renderer (local html file) have access to node.  I can require something native to node core such as `fs` and it works - when I try to require lodash, it returns an empty object. So far I have:

- installed `lodash` from `npm` to the local project (using `--save`)
- run `electron-rebuild`

I refresh the app and step through the debugger only to find that `lodash` is an empty object.

Am I missing something? Can you only run core node modules in a renderer?

Comment: Mention some more details.

Answer (score 0):

To use packages in the renderer, you simply have to load it as a dependency in your package.json file and require it by name. To make sure your dependencies are up to date:

- add the module's latest version to the `dependencies` object of your `package.json` file.
- delete your `node_modules/`folder
- run `npm install` on your project folder

You should now be able to simply do `require('module_name');` in your `renderer.js` file.